Error using smart forms with smart controls when entering numbers or dates
I am currently using smart forms to edit my data, but when I edit and put a number in a number field I get a verification error, in the same way with the date.
SmartForm
Console Error
<EntityType Name="Agreements">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="ID"/>
                    <PropertyRef Name="VALID_FROM"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="ID" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false"/>
                <Property Name="CREATED_AT" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Precision="7"/>
                <Property Name="CREATED_BY" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="255"/>
                <Property Name="MODIFIED_AT" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Precision="7"/>
                <Property Name="MODIFIED_BY" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="255"/>
                <Property Name="DELETED" Type="Edm.Boolean"/>
                <Property Name="DELETED_AT" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Precision="7"/>
                <Property Name="DELETED_BY" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="255"/>
                <Property Name="VALID_FROM" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Precision="7" Nullable="false"/>
                <Property Name="VALID_TO" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Precision="7"/>
                <Property Name="DESCRIPTION" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="250"/>
                <Property Name="CURRENCY" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="3"/>
                <Property Name="EXTERNAL_CONTRACT_IDENTIFIER" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="15"/>
                <Property Name="STATUS" Type="Edm.Boolean"/>
                <Property Name="DEACTIVATED_AT" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Precision="7"/>
                <Property Name="TYPE_CODE" Type="Edm.Int32"/>
                <Property Name="PRIORITY_CODE" Type="Edm.Int32"/>
                <NavigationProperty Name="BUSINESS_PARTNERS_PER_AGREEMENT" Relationship="Agreement.Agreements_BUSINESS_PARTNERS_PER_AGREEMENT" FromRole="Agreements" ToRole="Business_partners_per_agreement"/>
                <NavigationProperty Name="SITE_BUNDLES_HEADER" Relationship="Agreement.Agreements_SITE_BUNDLES_HEADER" FromRole="Agreements" ToRole="Site_bundles_headers"/>
                <NavigationProperty Name="ADDED_ELEMENT_TO_AGREMMENT" Relationship="Agreement.Agreements_ADDED_ELEMENT_TO_AGREMMENT" FromRole="Agreements" ToRole="Added_element_to_agremment"/>
                <NavigationProperty Name="SERVICES_PER_AGREEMENT" Relationship="Agreement.Agreements_SERVICES_PER_AGREEMENT" FromRole="Agreements" ToRole="services_per_agreement"/>
            </EntityType>

           <Annotations Target="Agreement.Agreements/ID">
                <Annotation Term="Common.FieldControl" EnumMember="Common.FieldControlType/ReadOnly" />
                <Annotation Term="Common.Label" String="{@i18n>id}" />
            </Annotations>

            <Annotations Target="Agreement.Agreements/EXTERNAL_CONTRACT_IDENTIFIER">
                <Annotation Term="Common.Label" String="{@i18n>externalContract}" />
            </Annotations>

            <Annotations Target="Agreement.Agreements/DESCRIPTION">
                <Annotation Term="Common.Label" String="{@i18n>description}" />
            </Annotations>

            <Annotations Target="Agreement.Agreements/VALID_FROM">
                <Annotation Term="Common.Label" String="{@i18n>startDate1}" />
                <Annotation Term="Common.FieldControl" EnumMember="Common.FieldControlType/Mandatory" />
                date
            </Annotations>

            <Annotations Target="Agreement.Agreements/VALID_TO">
                <Annotation Term="Common.Label" String="{@i18n>endDate}" />
            </Annotations>

            <Annotations Target="Agreement.Agreements/TYPE_CODE">
                <Annotation Term="Common.FieldControl" EnumMember="Common.FieldControlType/Mandatory" />
                <Annotation Term="Common.Label" String="{@i18n>agreementType}" />
            </Annotations>

            <Annotations Target="Agreement.Agreements/STATUS">
                <Annotation Term="Common.Label" String="{@i18n>status}" />
            </Annotations>

why does this happen and how can I fix? Thank you
I have tried to format the values ​​in the controller but the error still appears, however when I send the message it is executed correctly
